# How do you multiply rows by each other when certain conditions are met in Google Sheets?

Tags: matrix, google-sheets

I would like to find every possible combination of these 15 rows multiplied by each other. 
I currently have all of the combinations lined up. [This is a link to the spreadsheet I'm working on](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CRR6flt8XQiucGCQiOE7S9RxgH9LlfaFA_KBI2FrhLY/edit#gid=1622860054)

I want to multiply rows M:AD by M$14:AD$14 whenever the word "Aerodactyl" is also in the row.

Comment: Is "Aerodactyl" going to be in a particular column? Also, where should the output of multiplication appear? It can't replace the data that you are multiplying.

Comment: "Aerodactyl" Is a name that will appear periodically within the first 6 columns. It's just one of the initial 15 rows that I am multiplying all of the combinations for. 

The M:AD columns currently are in a =Q$2*Q$12*Q$5 format. I'd like to know if would be possible to add "*Q$14" onto the end automatically.